# External sound card not working with Windows 10

Tags: audio, drivers, sound-card, windows-10-preview

I appreciate Windows 10 is a preview edition of the software, so I can have no quarrels if some of it doesn't work.

However, my UA-25 external audio interface will not function with the January build of Windows 10. When trying to install the driver, nothing happens after Windows pops up the 'installing device driver software' dialog.

Is there anything I can do to try and solve the problem? Where can I look?

Comment: Did you try that sound card on another system? If everything works properly, then most probably is a bug on windows 10 preview... You can try with a linux live cd in case you can't try with other OS.

Comment: Yeah the soundcard is fine, works fine on an earlier version of the preview

Comment: this preview jumps from version 6.4 to 10.0, so the driver may not work with this change.

Comment: others also run into this: https://twitter.com/GabeAul/status/560109272172740608 Submit it in the Feedback app

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried restarting? Sometimes restarting helps.

Also:

**Step 1:** Right click on the sound icon http://prntscr.com/5x6ipg.
**Step 2:** Select playback devices.
**Step 3:** Select you playback device.
**Step 4:** Click configure.
**Step 5:** Click Test.
**Step 6:** Click next, next, Finish.

This worked for me when my sound wasn't working. I hope this works for you. If not, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Let me share what worked for me...
After upgrading to Windows 10, Sound was not working on my Laptop.
Following steps resolved the issue:
1. Right Click on the Speaker Icon
2. Select Playback Devices
3. Highlight Speakers... and click on Properties
4. Go to Enhancements Tab
5. Tick on Disable all enhancements.

This fixed it