# How to prevent Windows 10 Tech Preview from upgrading itself to a new test build?

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-preview

I've found [a Windows 10 bug](https://superuser.com/questions/869354/external-sound-card-not-working-with-windows-10) that essentially stops my computer from working. This bug is only present in the 9926 build so far. When I use Windows Rollback to go back to the previous 9879 build, there is no bug. However, after a couple of days, I get thrown back to 9926

So, is there a way of staying on the older 9879 build, without being automatically upgraded to 9926?

Comment: Disable `Windows Updates`.  At the end of the day if there is a bug you should report it so it can be fixed in the next released build or through an update.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah I have reported it

Comment: You can also use commercial software the saves the state of the machine

Comment: @Ramhound can you give some examples of this software?

Comment: Macrium Reflect Free is great, though I haven't tested it on Windows 10 yet.

Comment: @KeithLammers how would I use this to prevent the upgrading? (It looks more like recovery software)

Comment: Sorry, I was following up on @Ramhound's comment about saving the state of the machine. I assumed he was referring to disk imaging software, so that you can roll back if you run into trouble with future Win 10 updates, in a situation where Windows Rollback may not be working.

Comment: @KeithLammers - I was thinking more of a program the doesn't allow ANY changes to the system disk.  Various commercial applications that do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ramhound mentioned above, disabling Windows Updates by stopping and disabling the Windows Update service should do the trick:

1. Start > Run > services.msc
2. Double-click "Windows Update" in the Services console
3. Click Stop, change the Startup Type to Disabled, then click OK